# Resize ImageView after resizing and assigning bitmap

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an `ImageView` with bitmap resized to fit. Here is a screenshot

[image]

I have set White color to `ImageView` background. So `ImageView` is visible in all screen.

What i want is, when i set the image so that it fills it maximum how can i resize `ImageView` to fit the image drawable it is showing, that is resize `ImageView` so that it doesnt show any white color.

Comment: Are you okay with the image being stretched to be a bigger height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my issue

```
public class MyImageView extends CropImageView
{
    public int mVideoWidth  = 0;
    public int mVideoHeight = 0;

    private boolean isFixed = false;

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setImageSize(int width, int height)
    {
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // Log.i("@@@", "onMeasure");
        int width = getDefaultSize(mVideoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(mVideoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0)
        {
            if (mVideoWidth * height > width * mVideoHeight)
            {
                height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
            } else if (mVideoWidth * height < width * mVideoHeight)
            {
                width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
            } else
            {
                // Log.i("@@@", "aspect ratio is correct: " +
                // width+"/"+height+"="+
                // mVideoWidth+"/"+mVideoHeight);
            }
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `wrap_content` as its width and height

Comment: i tried but it makes image reduce its width and doest make it fit full screen

Answer (score 0):

set the scale type to fitXY in the xml file of the imageView like this:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/imageView" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/locked_image"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

Hope this will help you out..

Answer (score 0):

It will not fill all your screen (or it will be stetched)
just set `wrap_content` to `height`
and leave `match_parent` to `width`